# Call stack implementation in Programming languages

Tags: python, callstack, nested-function

I am taking a class on Programming languages. The tutor was explaining about call stacks. I had a doubt which the tutor couldn't explain properly. If a function(func1) returns a nested function(say func2 and let func2 uses variables defined in func1). And we save the returned value in some variable, say returnedFunc. The func1 would have got exited after the return statement in func1 got finished. And the stack frame of func1 should have got popped off the call stack. We now call returnedFunc some where else in code. But returnedFunc uses variables local to func1 whose stack frame no more exists in call stack. How does this work.

Example python code :

```
def func1():
    a = 3;
    def func2():
        print(a)
    return func2

returnedFunc = func1()
returnedFunc()
```

This piece of code correctly prints 3. Whereas I was expecting some garbage value since func1 no more exists on call stack

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The variables & their values from the outer function `func1` which the inner function `func2` uses are "packaged" with `func2` when the inner function is defined, and that "lexical environment" comes with `func2` when `func1` returns it. `func2` is what's called a [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29) (the example given at the top of the article is very similar to yours, and extends it a little). You're right that `func1`'s copy of `a` gets popped off the stack when that function returns, but the returned `func2` has a binding of `a` to `3`, which will be used when it's called via `returnedFunc()`. Python is smarter than to bind `a` to what will soon be garbage :)

To illustrate, let's use a slightly more complex example:

```
def outer(x):
    def inner(y):
        return x+y
    return inner

inner3 = outer(3)
inner5 = outer(5)
```

As you'd expect,

```
>>> inner3(1)
4
>>> inner5(1)
6
```

You can examine the bindings of a closure using the `inspect.getclosurevars`. Notice that each closure has its own copy of `'x'`:

```
from inspect import getclosurevars
>>> getclosurevars(inner3)
ClosureVars(nonlocals={'x': 3}, globals={}, builtins={}, unbound=set())
>>> getclosurevars(inner5)
ClosureVars(nonlocals={'x': 5}, globals={}, builtins={}, unbound=set())
```

However, if two closures use the same nonlocal variable, as in your example, the variable will be bound to the same location. Consider this situation (from a comment by the OP):

```
def func1():
    a = 3
    def func2():
        nonlocal a
        a += 1
        return a

    def func3():
        nonlocal a
        a -= 1
        return a

    return func2, func3

f2, f3 = func1()
```

Calling the functions `f2` and `f3` suggests that they use the same value of `a`:

```
>>> f2(), f2(), f3(), f3()
(4, 5, 4, 3)
```

Examining the `__closure__` attribute of each shows that this is indeed the case. The "cells" (bindings) are the same, and each "points to" the same int object:

```
>>> f2.__closure__
(<cell at 0x100380fa8: int object at 0x1002739a0>,)
>>> f2.__closure__ == f3.__closure__
True
```

A `cell` object (of class `cell`) has a `cell_contents` attribute; for `f2` and `f3` the `cell_contents` are int objects. Here's another verification that the two cells point to the same thing:

```
>>> f2.__closure__[0].cell_contents is f3.__closure__[0].cell_contents
True
```

In fact, the two cells are the same:

```
>>> f2.__closure__[0] is f3.__closure__[0]
True
```

Comment: Got it. You mean to say that the copy of `a` which is packaged in the closure of func2 is in the heap instead of the stack. Which means closures are stored in the heap?

Comment: Yes, the copy of `a` is part of a Python object, heap-allocated. Closures are callable Python objects, and are heap-allocated. When *called*, the call stack comes into play, of course; but that's not where they *reside*.

Comment: But what happens when func1 has 2 nested functions func2 and func3 both of which use the same variable local to func1. In such a case, the value of `a` should not be "packed" with closures of either of func2 or func3 but should be outside the closures and be shared by func2 and func3. Isn't it?

Comment: No I mean, func1 has 2 nested functions. `def func1 {def func2; def func3}`. If both func2 & func3 use the same varible which is local to func1, then it should be outside the closures and be a common memory right?

Comment: Indeed they are :) They refer to the same value. This is actually good and what one would expect. Yes if you look at `__closure__` its `repr` shows the addresses of the cells and of the int values (value of `a`) and they're the same. They're different in my example because the values come from the parameter (passed different arguments on different calls) rather than the same nonlocal as in your example.

Comment: @salsabear I updated my answer to incorporate your example from these comments.

Comment: Easier to read than addresses : `f2.__closure__ == f3.__closure__` ; evaluates to `True`.

Comment: You're right, it is. I kept the first `f2.__closure__` just to show "what's in there" but replaced the final expression with your suggestion.

Comment: @salsabear somehow I suspect the tutor is gonna be learning a lot this term.

Answer (score 1):

Python is different. It has its own byte-code compiler, interpreter, and stack. It doesn't use the C/machine stack for the Python code itself. Also your example creates a new function. It's allocated as an object on the heap, not on the stack. So it exists after the return.

Answer (score 0):

`func2` still contains a copy of the [**scope**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29#Python) that contained it, assigned by the compiler, since it uses a name found in that scope.